# Inserting Jquery script file

Tags: yii

Hy guys!
On my site I noticed that on some pages I don't have a Jquery library included. But on other pages I see it in my head tag:

```
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fe9bd624/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fe9bd624/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
```

In my theme layout/main.php I don't have Jquery files in head tag. So question is: what controls inserting Jquery on my pages, and how to insert it on all pages. Thx.

Comment: I've inserted next line in my layout file: <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>. So now Jquery works on all pages. But where I can find a list of pages on which Jquery inserts automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery would only be inserted automatically if you call the registerCoreScript method. There's nothing built into Yii to force jQuery upon you.

However, it could be that your using a widget or extension somewhere that uses jQuery, which would make it's own call to the registerCoreScript. (CGridView for example)

Comment: One more thing that I noticed, the jquery will be auto inserted above the <title> tag in head section, so you can add the CSS above it and rest of your jquery dependent js below it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any widget or component or extension which needs  jquery & using function registerCoreScript than jquery will be loaded automatically otherwise YII does not load any JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In every view that requires jquery you can put this on top:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

You can put it into your layout also if you want to include in all pages in a particular layout.